# How do I run a query in SQL Developer to determine what accounts have admin roles?

Tags: sql, oracle, admin, account, system-administration

I've been asked to run a query to find accounts in the following admin roles in Oracle: SQL:Syslogins
sysadmin, securityadmin, serveradmin, processadmin, diskadmin, dbcreator, bulkadmin

Comment: This looks like a lot like  [SQL Server roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) . Are you really sure that this for Oracle database ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize any of those names. Are these roles created specific to your installation?  If so they can be identified as such in DBA_ROLES.  As for who has them, that gets into recursive issues -- role granted to role granted to role granted to user.  For that, I recommend Pete Finnigan's script - [who_has_role](http://www.petefinnigan.com/who_has_role.sql).